# Setting field of a subclass via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to set a value of a field of a subclass object:

```
public void setValue(Serializable target, String fieldName, float changer) {
...
//next I'm accessing field "deal" of sub-class "Mon" of class "Hum"
//Hum target
//String upper value is "Mon"
//String fieldName value is "deal"
//float changer is some valid number
Field theField = target.getClass().getDeclaredField(upper).get(target).getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
switch (theField.getType().getName()) {
    case "float":
        theField.setFloat(target, changer); //the line with error!
        break;
    case "int":
...
}
```

The code throws

```
IllegalArgumentException: Can not set float field hb.Hum$Mon.deal to hb.Hum
```

OK, but when I changed the troubled line to:

```
theField.setFloat(target.getClass().getDeclaredField(upper).get(target).getClass(), changer)
```

it threw a `NullPointerException`.
I'm obviously messing up with field access but I can't figure out what exactly I do wrong. Can anyone, please, point to a mistake?

**PS**

The working code is (I shouldn't have called getClass() the second time):

```
theField.setFloat(target.getClass().getDeclaredField(upper).get(target), changer)
```

Comment: first of all : **split up your statements**, you will never find the cuplrit if you write your entire program within one single line - use variables, thats what they're made for. And then please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with what your code does, but with how you are calling it. You are passing an instance of the outer class `hb.Hum` for the target, while the code expects a *nested class* `hb.Hum.Mon`.

You need to make sure that when you call `setValue` the first parameter is of the correct type. This will fix the problem.